# Only allow one login session to be active at a time

Tags: login, session, account

Is there any way to restrict accounts to login only once at the same time? Ex. Mike bought a subscription from my website and also lent it to his friend John. What I want to achieve is preventing Mike login if John is already logged in and the opposite. Is this possible?

Comment: Try these resources. it will help you 1. http://wordpress.org/plugins/login-only-1-session/ 2. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5639832/1465973 3. http://wordpress.org/plugins/limit-login-attempts/